# Parameter order is incorrect when calling Oracle stored procedures using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I am using latest Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client 11.2 .dll for getting data from Oracle to .net application. Is it required to pass parameter in same order as expected by the stored procedure?

From application side we are add parameter order to command object cmd is

```
KK_C
KK_C2
KK_C1
```

Stored procedure like

```
KK_C
KK_C1
KK_C2
```

And this is generic code I am not able pass parameter same order what the stored procedure expected. Because different stored procedures expect different parameter order

My method:

```
Public Function GetDataTable(ByRef xmlParams As XmlNodeList) As DataTable
{
     Dim param As OracleParameter

     Dim params As List(Of OracleParameter) = New List(Of OracleParameter)()

     For Each node As XmlNode In xmlParams

param = New OracleParameter()

param.ParameterName = Convert.ToString(node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText)

param.OracleDbType = CType("112", OracleDbType)

 param.Value =Convert.ToString(node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText)


   Next

 Dim addparam As OracleParameter
            Dim cmd As OracleCommand
            Dim objdt As DataTable
            OpenConnection()
            cmd = New OracleCommand()           
            cmd.Connection = _oracleConn            
            cmd.CommandText = sql           
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure           

            If Not params Is Nothing Then
                For Each param As OracleParameter In params             
                    addparam = New OracleParameter()

                    With addparam                   
                        .Direction = param.Direction
                        .OracleDbType = param.OracleDbType 
                        If Left(param.ParameterName, 2) <> "KK_" Then
                            .ParameterName = "KK_" & param.ParameterName
                        Else
                            .ParameterName = param.ParameterName
                        End If
                        .Size = param.Size
                        .Value = param.Value
                    End With
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(addparam)

                Next
            End If

            addparam = New OracleParameter("OO_remcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)
            addparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            cmd.Parameters.Add(addparam)

            'fill the datatable
            objdt = New DataTable(tblname)

            Using objda As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)

                objda.Fill(objdt)

            End Using
            Return objdt
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE GetDATA(KK_C IN NUMBER,KK_C1 IN NUMBER, KK_C2 IN NUMBER OO_remCursor OUT o_Cursor)
    AS
    BEGIN
        OPEN o_remCursor FOR
        SELECT ....        ORDER BY LOWER(brand_alias);

    END GetDATA;
```

Comment: Can't you just change the order of the nodes in the XmlNodeList?

Comment: but its not possible to change order in XmlNodeList.

Comment: I found solution.
  Dim cmd As OracleCommand =New OracleCommand()
 cmd.BindByName = True

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by "Praveen G", if you want to call a stored procedure with named parameters without taking care of the paramaters declaration order, simply set "BindByName" to true

```
cmd.BindByName = True
```

Unfortunately, this property is not true by default (maybe for performance reasons)...