# Unable to fill DataTable from OracleRefCursor

Tags: c#, oracle, sys-refcursor

I have followed all questions here and both .Net & Oracle documentation, and found no hope but to get help here!

I have a procedure that returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR`

I managed to retreive it as outparam, but having a hard time figuring out what's the problem with filling the `DataTable` from the cursor

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("pView", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

OracleRefCursor cursor = (OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters["pView"].Value;
// cursor.RowSize = 2540

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int rowsCount = da.Fill(dt, cursor);                     
// rowsCount = 0
```

Comment: Given that we can't run your code it would be helpful if you actually explained the problem you're having. Describe the behaviour, including any error messages you get.

Comment: I don't get any error message, just that the `DataTable` is empty, while the cursor has 2k+ rows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a really big hasstle, it seemed that the `RowSize` & `FetchSize` are **irreliable**!

The problem was with the parameters arriving incorrectly to the database *(order of parameters!)*

But thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214908/parameter-order-is-incorrect-when-calling-oracle-stored-procedures-using-oracle#comment24941887_17214908) it's solvable by setting `cmd.BindByName = true;`